# How to authenticate via LDAP or Active Directory using MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, ldap

I've found many threads about authenticating using LDAP but it's more about asp.net webforms and MVC 3 not 4. I'm using VS2012 MVC 4 Web Application and Internet Application project template. I'm trying to authenticate via LDAP or Active Directory and so far there is no step by step instruction I've found that works. It's mostly one sample here and there and it didn't really works. I've tried the Microsoft asp.net forum but so far no one seems to know the answer. So, below is my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="alumniConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=myDB;Initial Catalog=Alumn;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://mySite.com/ou=useraccounts,DC=mySite,DC=com"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <!--<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />-->
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="30" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="SimpleProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SimpleProfileProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionUsername="mySite-UserName\myLDAP" connectionPassword="myPassLDAP" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

As soon as I enter the Account/Login page, I received the following errors:

> Server Error in '/Alumni' Application. Unable to find the requested
>   .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed. Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the
>   requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

```
Source Error:


Line 32:                     using (var context = new UsersContext())
Line 33:                     {
Line 34:                         if (!context.Database.Exists())
Line 35:                         {
Line 36:                             // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema


Source File: f:\Web_Site\Alumni\Alumni\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs Line: 34
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not
>   be installed.

Have you checked if the following is in your site's bin folder:

- WebMatrix.Data.dll
- WebMatrix.WebData.dll
- EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can use the SimpleMembershipProvider with LDAP. You have to be going against a SQL database.